# Unable to find type [System.Net.Webutility]

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a script on Windows 2008 Server, but not sure if I can run it. I'm getting the following error message:

`Unable to find type [System.Net.Webutility]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.`

As stated, I'm trying to run this on 2008 Server. According to System.Net.Webutility documentation, it's been available since Windows 8. Am I SOL or is there a work around?

Below is my code:

```
#account of the Shared Mailbox
$account = "MyAccount@myaddress.com"

#date to append to new file name
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd

#Formatted date to search Inbox
$searchDate = Get-Date -Format M/dd/yyyy
Write-Host "Searching for $searchDate..."

#file to save attachment as
$newFileName = "Record_Import_$date.html"

#file name for the XML File
$newXMLFileName = "Record_Import_$date.xml"

#File paths Main directory, HTML, HTML Record and Raw folders
$newFilePath = "\\PathA\"
$newHTMLPath = "\\PathB\"
$newHTMLRecordPath = "\\PathC\"
$rawFilePath = "\\PathD\"

#Go into Outlook and get the MAPI
$mail = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$mailNS = $mail.GetNamespace("MAPI")

#print out Accounts in MAPI
foreach($email in $mailNS.Folders)
{
    Write-Host $email.Name
}

Write-Host "---"

#get the account and Inbox we want
$myAcount = $mailNS.Folders | ? {$_.Name -eq $account}

#Print out folders in Shared Inbox
foreach($folder in $myAcount.Folders)
{
    Write-Host $folder.Name
}

#Get the inbox of the account
$myInbox = $myAcount.Folders | ? {$_.Name -eq "Inbox"};

#loop through the Inbox and get any Attachments with the extension of ".EXCEL"
foreach ($f in $myInbox)
{
    foreach($i in $f.Items)
    {

        if($i.ReceivedTime.Date -eq $searchDate)
        {

            Write-Host "---"
            Write-Host "Checking "$i.Subject"..."
            Write-Host "---"

            foreach($a in $i.Attachments)
            {
                if($a.FileName -like "*.MYFILETYPE")
                {
                    #Move the attachment to the desired directory and save the raw file in the Raw directory
                    $a.SaveAsFile((Join-Path $newHTMLPath $newFileName))
                    $a.SaveAsFile((Join-Path $rawFilePath $a.FileName))
                    Write-Host $a.FileName " Saved as HTML"

                    #Open the HTML file and parse it
                    $htmlString = Get-Content (Join-Path $newHTMLPath $newFileName)
                    [xml]$html = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlDecode($htmlString);

                    #Get the date of the HTML File
                    $dateSpan = $html.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode('//tr[2]/td[2]').InnerText

                    #Reset the newXMLFileName and newFileName variables to include the new date
                    $newXMLFileName = "BAI_Import_$dateSpan.xml"
                    $newFileName = "BAI_Import_$dateSpan.html"
                    $a.SaveAsFile((Join-Path $newHTMLRecordPath $newFileName))

                    Write-Host "Date for XML is $dateSpan"

                    $xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Date>
'@;
                    $xml = $xml += $dateSpan 
                    $xml = $xml += @'
</Date>
<Cash Activities>

'@;
                    $rows = $html.DocumentElement.SelectNodes('//tr');
                    $pastVariance = $false
                    foreach ($row in $rows) 
                    {
                        if ($row.GetAttribute('class') -eq 'c12') 
                        {
                            $xml += "`t<Cash Activity>`n";
                            $spans = $row.SelectNodes('.//descendant::span[@class]');
                            if ($spans.Count -eq 2) 
                            {
                                $spanCheck = $spans[0].InnerText.Trim();
                                Write-Host $spanCheck

                                if($pastVariance)
                                {
                                    $xml += "`t`t<Activity>Unknown Cash Activity</Activity>`n";
                                } Else 
                                {
                                    $xml += "`t`t<Activity>$($spans[0].InnerText.Trim())</Activity>`n"; 
                                }
                                $xml += "`t`t<Balance>$($spans[1].InnerText.Trim())</Balance>`n"; 

                                #check to make sure that this line was a Variance
                                if($spanCheck -match "Variance")
                                {
                                    $pastVariance = $true
                                }

                            }
                            $xml += "`t</Cash Activity>`n";
                        }
                    }


                    $xml += @'
</Cash Activities>
'@;
                    Write-Host $xml
                    $xml | Out-File (Join-Path $newFilePath $newXMLFileName)
                    Write-Host $i.Subject " Exported to XML File"
                }#End of EXCEL Check
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have at least .NET Framework 4 installed?

Comment: Yes: 4.0.30319 is currently installed

Comment: What happens if you enter `[Net.WebUtility]` at a PowerShell prompt?

Comment: Unable to find type. Should I try to `Add-Type -AssemblyName Net.Webutility` ?

Comment: I just learned that we're running Powershell 2. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, because it only "sees" .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

[System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) has been available since **.NET Framework 1.1**, so you can alternatively accomplish the same thing like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;

$encoded = '<span class="c2">FRIDAY&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($encoded);
```

Comment: Just adjusted my code and that's a no-go. Still can't find the type

Comment: @jDave1984 - That's surprising, I tested on two Windows 7 workstations on different environments/networks running PowerShell 2. And I could be wrong, but am pretty sure `[System.Web.HttpUtility]` is included with the standard .NET 2. Framework. Would you verify that all instances of `[System.Net.WebUtility]` were replaced with `[System.Web.HttpUtility]` in your script? When I first tested this, I forgot to do the replacement myself...

Comment: @jDave1984 - and since you're running PowerShell 2, you can also try replacing `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;` with `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web') | Out-Null;`. [Here's an explanation](https://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/add-type-vs-reflectionassembly-in.html) of `Add-Type` vs `[reflection.assembly]`

Comment: Too late. Already submitted a ticket to get that box's powershell upgraded

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Install [Windows Management Framework 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) to get PowerShell 5.1 on there, but beware that it's a system wide change and some software (Exchange, particularly) doesn't support changing the PowerShell version.

Workaround: Your code is only using it to do a single HTMLDecode, and that's not a very complicated operation; [here is the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Net/WebUtility.cs#L168) for that method in .Net Core, so either inline that in C# somehow or port it to PowerShell.

Which I did, and it took me a lot longer than intended - serves me right for starting with "not a very complicated operation", I didn't realise it had to handle multibyte unicode, and had memory-performance optimisations in the lookup table and they clashed with PowerShell string handling, etc. ;)  but here it is:

```
[char]$HIGH_SURROGATE_START = 0xD800
[char]$LOW_SURROGATE_START = 0xDC00
[char]$LOW_SURROGATE_END = 0xDFFF
[int]$UNICODE_PLANE00_END = 0x00FFFF
[int]$UNICODE_PLANE01_START = 0x10000
[int]$UNICODE_PLANE16_END = 0x10FFFF

function ConvertTo-Uint64Key ([char[]]$entity) {

    # The ulong key is the reversed single-byte character representation of the actual entity string.

    [uint64]$key = 0

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $entity.Length; $i++)
    {
        if ($entity[$i] -gt 0xFF)
        {
            return 0
        }

        $key = ($key -shl 8) -bor $entity[$i]
    }

    $key

}

# To avoid an allocation, keys of type "ulong" are used in the lookup table.
# Since all entity strings comprise 8 characters or less and are ASCII-only, they "fit" into an ulong (8 bytes).
# This is a port of the C#, with the keys inlined and the entity code in the comment.

$htmlEntityLookup = @{
    [uint64]1903521652           = [char]0x22         # quot
    [uint64]6385008              = [char]0x26         # amp
    [uint64]1634758515           = [char]0x27         # apos
    [uint64]27764                = [char]0x3c         # lt
    [uint64]26484                = [char]0x3e         # gt
    [uint64]1851945840           = [char]0xa0         # nbsp
    [uint64]452673954668         = [char]0xa1         # iexcl
    [uint64]1667591796           = [char]0xa2         # cent
    [uint64]482906304100         = [char]0xa3         # pound
    [uint64]109356082423150      = [char]0xa4         # curren
    [uint64]7955822              = [char]0xa5         # yen
    [uint64]108243751952754      = [char]0xa6         # brvbar
    [uint64]1936024436           = [char]0xa7         # sect
    [uint64]7695724              = [char]0xa8         # uml
    [uint64]1668247673           = [char]0xa9         # copy
    [uint64]1869767782           = [char]0xaa         # ordf
    [uint64]465491293551         = [char]0xab         # laquo
    [uint64]7237492              = [char]0xac         # not
    [uint64]7563385              = [char]0xad         # shy
    [uint64]7497063              = [char]0xae         # reg
    [uint64]1835098994           = [char]0xaf         # macr
    [uint64]6579559              = [char]0xb0         # deg
    [uint64]123611129277806      = [char]0xb1         # plusmn
    [uint64]1937076274           = [char]0xb2         # sup2
    [uint64]1937076275           = [char]0xb3         # sup3
    [uint64]418280469605         = [char]0xb4         # acute
    [uint64]469919560303         = [char]0xb5         # micro
    [uint64]1885434465           = [char]0xb6         # para
    [uint64]120299423297396      = [char]0xb7         # middot
    [uint64]426902841708         = [char]0xb8         # cedil
    [uint64]1937076273           = [char]0xb9         # sup1
    [uint64]1869767789           = [char]0xba         # ordm
    [uint64]491261097327         = [char]0xbb         # raquo
    [uint64]112641446195508      = [char]0xbc         # frac14
    [uint64]112641446195506      = [char]0xbd         # frac12
    [uint64]112641446196020      = [char]0xbe         # frac34
    [uint64]115936021803892      = [char]0xbf         # iquest
    [uint64]71912556426853       = [char]0xc0         # Agrave
    [uint64]71886536275045       = [char]0xc1         # Aacute
    [uint64]280840729187         = [char]0xc2         # Acirc
    [uint64]71968240723045       = [char]0xc3         # Atilde
    [uint64]1098214764           = [char]0xc4         # Auml
    [uint64]281092386407         = [char]0xc5         # Aring
    [uint64]280337607015         = [char]0xc6         # AElig
    [uint64]74094181902700       = [char]0xc7         # Ccedil
    [uint64]76310602937957       = [char]0xc8         # Egrave
    [uint64]76284582786149       = [char]0xc9         # Eacute
    [uint64]298020598371         = [char]0xca         # Ecirc
    [uint64]1165323628           = [char]0xcb         # Euml
    [uint64]80708649449061       = [char]0xcc         # Igrave
    [uint64]80682629297253       = [char]0xcd         # Iacute
    [uint64]315200467555         = [char]0xce         # Icirc
    [uint64]1232432492           = [char]0xcf         # Iuml
    [uint64]4543560              = [char]0xd0         # ETH
    [uint64]86261891884133       = [char]0xd1         # Ntilde
    [uint64]87305719215717       = [char]0xd2         # Ograve
    [uint64]87279699063909       = [char]0xd3         # Oacute
    [uint64]340970271331         = [char]0xd4         # Ocirc
    [uint64]87361403511909       = [char]0xd5         # Otilde
    [uint64]1333095788           = [char]0xd6         # Ouml
    [uint64]499984983411         = [char]0xd7         # times
    [uint64]87357158159208       = [char]0xd8         # Oslash
    [uint64]93902788982373       = [char]0xd9         # Ugrave
    [uint64]93876768830565       = [char]0xda         # Uacute
    [uint64]366740075107         = [char]0xdb         # Ucirc
    [uint64]1433759084           = [char]0xdc         # Uuml
    [uint64]98274815341669       = [char]0xdd         # Yacute
    [uint64]361990410830         = [char]0xde         # THORN
    [uint64]495975164263         = [char]0xdf         # szlig
    [uint64]107096928515685      = [char]0xe0         # agrave
    [uint64]107070908363877      = [char]0xe1         # aacute
    [uint64]418279682659         = [char]0xe2         # acirc
    [uint64]107152612811877      = [char]0xe3         # atilde
    [uint64]1635085676           = [char]0xe4         # auml
    [uint64]418531339879         = [char]0xe5         # aring
    [uint64]418313431399         = [char]0xe6         # aelig
    [uint64]109278553991532      = [char]0xe7         # ccedil
    [uint64]111494975026789      = [char]0xe8         # egrave
    [uint64]111468954874981      = [char]0xe9         # eacute
    [uint64]435459551843         = [char]0xea         # ecirc
    [uint64]1702194540           = [char]0xeb         # euml
    [uint64]115893021537893      = [char]0xec         # igrave
    [uint64]115867001386085      = [char]0xed         # iacute
    [uint64]452639421027         = [char]0xee         # icirc
    [uint64]1769303404           = [char]0xef         # iuml
    [uint64]6648936              = [char]0xf0         # eth
    [uint64]121446263972965      = [char]0xf1         # ntilde
    [uint64]122490091304549      = [char]0xf2         # ograve
    [uint64]122464071152741      = [char]0xf3         # oacute
    [uint64]478409224803         = [char]0xf4         # ocirc
    [uint64]122545775600741      = [char]0xf5         # otilde
    [uint64]1869966700           = [char]0xf6         # ouml
    [uint64]110404120962149      = [char]0xf7         # divide
    [uint64]122541530248040      = [char]0xf8         # oslash
    [uint64]129087161071205      = [char]0xf9         # ugrave
    [uint64]129061140919397      = [char]0xfa         # uacute
    [uint64]504179028579         = [char]0xfb         # ucirc
    [uint64]1970629996           = [char]0xfc         # uuml
    [uint64]133459187430501      = [char]0xfd         # yacute
    [uint64]499968340590         = [char]0xfe         # thorn
    [uint64]2037738860           = [char]0xff         # yuml
    [uint64]340467149159         = [char]0x152        # OElig
    [uint64]478442973543         = [char]0x153        # oelig
    [uint64]91686301757294       = [char]0x160        # Scaron
    [uint64]126870673846126      = [char]0x161        # scaron
    [uint64]1500867948           = [char]0x178        # Yuml
    [uint64]1718513510           = [char]0x192        # fnof
    [uint64]1667854947           = [char]0x2c6        # circ
    [uint64]499984917605         = [char]0x2dc        # tilde
    [uint64]280992180321         = [char]0x391        # Alpha
    [uint64]1113945185           = [char]0x392        # Beta
    [uint64]306577239393         = [char]0x393        # Gamma
    [uint64]293759382625         = [char]0x394        # Delta
    [uint64]19545414385299310    = [char]0x395        # Epsilon
    [uint64]1516598369           = [char]0x396        # Zeta
    [uint64]4551777              = [char]0x397        # Eta
    [uint64]362528732257         = [char]0x398        # Theta
    [uint64]1232041057           = [char]0x399        # Iota
    [uint64]323757305953         = [char]0x39a        # Kappa
    [uint64]83981330703457       = [char]0x39b        # Lambda
    [uint64]19829                = [char]0x39c        # Mu
    [uint64]20085                = [char]0x39d        # Nu
    [uint64]22633                = [char]0x39e        # Xi
    [uint64]22356822567579502    = [char]0x39f        # Omicron
    [uint64]20585                = [char]0x3a0        # Pi
    [uint64]5400687              = [char]0x3a1        # Rho
    [uint64]358250671457         = [char]0x3a3        # Sigma
    [uint64]5529973              = [char]0x3a4        # Tau
    [uint64]24049014012669806    = [char]0x3a5        # Upsilon
    [uint64]5269609              = [char]0x3a6        # Phi
    [uint64]4417641              = [char]0x3a7        # Chi
    [uint64]5272425              = [char]0x3a8        # Psi
    [uint64]341137778529         = [char]0x3a9        # Omega
    [uint64]418431133793         = [char]0x3b1        # alpha
    [uint64]1650816097           = [char]0x3b2        # beta
    [uint64]444016192865         = [char]0x3b3        # gamma
    [uint64]431198336097         = [char]0x3b4        # delta
    [uint64]28552613640040302    = [char]0x3b5        # epsilon
    [uint64]2053469281           = [char]0x3b6        # zeta
    [uint64]6648929              = [char]0x3b7        # eta
    [uint64]499967685729         = [char]0x3b8        # theta
    [uint64]1768911969           = [char]0x3b9        # iota
    [uint64]461196259425         = [char]0x3ba        # kappa
    [uint64]119165702792289      = [char]0x3bb        # lambda
    [uint64]28021                = [char]0x3bc        # mu
    [uint64]28277                = [char]0x3bd        # nu
    [uint64]30825                = [char]0x3be        # xi
    [uint64]31364021822320494    = [char]0x3bf        # omicron
    [uint64]28777                = [char]0x3c0        # pi
    [uint64]7497839              = [char]0x3c1        # rho
    [uint64]126896543981926      = [char]0x3c2        # sigmaf
    [uint64]495689624929         = [char]0x3c3        # sigma
    [uint64]7627125              = [char]0x3c4        # tau
    [uint64]33056213267410798    = [char]0x3c5        # upsilon
    [uint64]7366761              = [char]0x3c6        # phi
    [uint64]6514793              = [char]0x3c7        # chi
    [uint64]7369577              = [char]0x3c8        # psi
    [uint64]478576732001         = [char]0x3c9        # omega
    [uint64]8388065856503118189  = [char]0x3d1        # thetasym
    [uint64]504397785448         = [char]0x3d2        # upsih
    [uint64]7367030              = [char]0x3d6        # piv
    [uint64]1701737328           = [char]0x2002       # ensp
    [uint64]1701671792           = [char]0x2003       # emsp
    [uint64]127991794266992      = [char]0x2009       # thinsp
    [uint64]2054647402           = [char]0x200c       # zwnj
    [uint64]8025962              = [char]0x200d       # zwj
    [uint64]7107181              = [char]0x200e       # lrm
    [uint64]7498861              = [char]0x200f       # rlm
    [uint64]474130510696         = [char]0x2013       # ndash
    [uint64]469835543400         = [char]0x2014       # mdash
    [uint64]465793283439         = [char]0x2018       # lsquo
    [uint64]491563087215         = [char]0x2019       # rsquo
    [uint64]495572841839         = [char]0x201a       # sbquo
    [uint64]465541625199         = [char]0x201c       # ldquo
    [uint64]491311428975         = [char]0x201d       # rdquo
    [uint64]422591952239         = [char]0x201e       # bdquo
    [uint64]110369509434738      = [char]0x2020       # dagger
    [uint64]75185137345906       = [char]0x2021       # Dagger
    [uint64]1651862636           = [char]0x2022       # bull
    [uint64]114784820029808      = [char]0x2026       # hellip
    [uint64]123581013780844      = [char]0x2030       # permil
    [uint64]482955849061         = [char]0x2032       # prime
    [uint64]345516895589         = [char]0x2033       # Prime
    [uint64]119242811864431      = [char]0x2039       # lsaquo
    [uint64]125839881631087      = [char]0x203a       # rsaquo
    [uint64]478560218725         = [char]0x203e       # oline
    [uint64]440005653356         = [char]0x2044       # frasl
    [uint64]1702195823           = [char]0x20ac       # euro
    [uint64]452806666085         = [char]0x2111       # image
    [uint64]131277443658352      = [char]0x2118       # weierp
    [uint64]1919246700           = [char]0x211c       # real
    [uint64]500135191653         = [char]0x2122       # trade
    [uint64]27422255507274093    = [char]0x2135       # alefsym
    [uint64]1818325618           = [char]0x2190       # larr
    [uint64]1969320562           = [char]0x2191       # uarr
    [uint64]1918988914           = [char]0x2192       # rarr
    [uint64]1684107890           = [char]0x2193       # darr
    [uint64]1751216754           = [char]0x2194       # harr
    [uint64]427120751218         = [char]0x21b5       # crarr
    [uint64]1816228466           = [char]0x21d0       # lArr
    [uint64]1967223410           = [char]0x21d1       # uArr
    [uint64]1916891762           = [char]0x21d2       # rArr
    [uint64]1682010738           = [char]0x21d3       # dArr
    [uint64]1749119602           = [char]0x21d4       # hArr
    [uint64]112628846390380      = [char]0x2200       # forall
    [uint64]1885434484           = [char]0x2202       # part
    [uint64]435811873652         = [char]0x2203       # exist
    [uint64]435627783289         = [char]0x2205       # empty
    [uint64]474080242785         = [char]0x2207       # nabla
    [uint64]1769171310           = [char]0x2208       # isin
    [uint64]474316302702         = [char]0x2209       # notin
    [uint64]28265                = [char]0x220b       # ni
    [uint64]1886547812           = [char]0x220f       # prod
    [uint64]7566701              = [char]0x2211       # sum
    [uint64]469920281971         = [char]0x2212       # minus
    [uint64]119226000044916      = [char]0x2217       # lowast
    [uint64]491260242275         = [char]0x221a       # radic
    [uint64]1886547824           = [char]0x221d       # prop
    [uint64]452823771502         = [char]0x221e       # infin
    [uint64]6385255              = [char]0x2220       # ang
    [uint64]6385252              = [char]0x2227       # and
    [uint64]28530                = [char]0x2228       # or
    [uint64]6513008              = [char]0x2229       # cap
    [uint64]6518128              = [char]0x222a       # cup
    [uint64]6909556              = [char]0x222b       # int
    [uint64]127991727416628      = [char]0x2234       # there4
    [uint64]7563629              = [char]0x223c       # sim
    [uint64]1668247143           = [char]0x2245       # cong
    [uint64]418549165424         = [char]0x2248       # asymp
    [uint64]28261                = [char]0x2260       # ne
    [uint64]435695217014         = [char]0x2261       # equiv
    [uint64]27749                = [char]0x2264       # le
    [uint64]26469                = [char]0x2265       # ge
    [uint64]7566690              = [char]0x2282       # sub
    [uint64]7566704              = [char]0x2283       # sup
    [uint64]1853060450           = [char]0x2284       # nsub
    [uint64]1937072741           = [char]0x2286       # sube
    [uint64]1937076325           = [char]0x2287       # supe
    [uint64]478627526003         = [char]0x2295       # oplus
    [uint64]122545775666547      = [char]0x2297       # otimes
    [uint64]1885696624           = [char]0x22a5       # perp
    [uint64]1935961972           = [char]0x22c5       # sdot
    [uint64]465524058476         = [char]0x2308       # lceil
    [uint64]491293862252         = [char]0x2309       # rceil
    [uint64]119187161706354      = [char]0x230a       # lfloor
    [uint64]125784231473010      = [char]0x230b       # rfloor
    [uint64]1818324583           = [char]0x2329       # lang
    [uint64]1918987879           = [char]0x232a       # rang
    [uint64]7106426              = [char]0x25ca       # loz
    [uint64]126926507500915      = [char]0x2660       # spades
    [uint64]427021394547         = [char]0x2663       # clubs
    [uint64]114784635876467      = [char]0x2665       # hearts
    [uint64]431264722291         = [char]0x2666       # diams
}

function ConvertFrom-EncodedHTML ($Text)
{

    [regex]::Replace($Text, '&(.{1,8});', {

        param($match)

        $entityCode = $match.Groups[1].Value

        switch ($entityCode)
        {
            # numeric entity
            # The # syntax can be in decimal or hex, e.g.
            #      &#229;  --> decimal
            #      &#xE5;  --> same char in hex
            # See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#entities

            {$entityCode[0] -eq '#'} {

                [uint32]$parsedValue = 0

                if ($entityCode[1] -eq 'x')
                {
                    $parsedSuccessfully = [uint32]::TryParse($entityCode.SubString(2), [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowHexSpecifier, [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [ref]$parsedValue)
                }
                else
                {
                    $parsedSuccessfully = [uint32]::TryParse($entityCode.SubString(1), [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::Integer, [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [ref]$parsedValue)
                }

                if ($parsedSuccessfully)
                {
                    # decoded character must be U+0000 .. U+10FFFF, excluding surrogates
                    $parsedSuccessfully = (($parsedValue -lt $HIGH_SURROGATE_START) -or ([int]$LOW_SURROGATE_END -lt $parsedValue -and $parsedValue -le $UNICODE_PLANE16_END))
                }

                if ($parsedSuccessfully)
                {
                    if ($parsedValue -le $UNICODE_PLANE00_END)
                    {
                        # single character
                        [char]$parsedValue
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        # multi-character
                        # "Convert supplementary multilingual plane to utf16"
                        # similar to Char.ConvertFromUtf32, but doesn't check arguments or generate strings
                        # input is assumed to be an SMP character
                        [int] $utf32 = ($parsedValue - $UNICODE_PLANE01_START)
                        $remainder = 0
                        [char]$leadingSurrogate = ([math]::DivRem($utf32, 0x400, [ref]$remainder) + $HIGH_SURROGATE_START)
                        [char]$trailingSurrogate = ($remainder + $LOW_SURROGATE_START)
                        '{0}{1}' -f $leadingSurrogate, $trailingSurrogate
                    }

                }

            }

            default {

                $entityChar = $htmlEntityLookup[[uint64](ConvertTo-Uint64Key $entityCode)]
                if ($entityChar -and $entityChar -ne [char]0)
                {
                    # return looked up char
                    return $entityChar
                }

                # return it as original text
                "&$entityCode;"
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Then

```
ConvertFrom-EncodedHTML 'o with combined diacritic o&#771;, euro &#8364;.'
ConvertFrom-EncodedHTML 'This &lt; that &gt; the other'
ConvertFrom-EncodedHTML 'test &nochange; old italic multibyte character in the supplementary multilingual plane &#x10300; &#x10301;'
```

becomes

```
o with combined diacritic õ, euro €.
This < that > the other
test &nochange; old italic multibyte character in the supplementary multilingual plane
```

And you might be able to:

```
[xml]$html = ConvertFrom-EncodedHTML $htmlString
```

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure upgrading a few thousand computers to .NET 5.1 is the fix I'm looking for :P